# Configure Visual Studio Code to highlight code blocks

Tags: visual-studio-code

Qt Creator has a really nice feature where based on the cursor location, they change the background color of the **rest** of the buffer to make it easy to see the block of code one is working in. They have two levels of highlighting - please see picture.

I've been trying to recreate this in VSCode but with no luck.

[image: Qt Creator showing highlight blocks]

I tried various VSCode settings and they don't seem to scope down to the block.

Blockman is visually very noisy i.e. I'd really like to have the lines have the background changed.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockman is visually very noisy

Hello, author of Blockman here. Blockman has so many configurations that can be used to reduce the noisy visual of default Blockman behavior. You can hide all blocks and show only the focused block. Also you can show +-1 or +-2 or +-3 ..... depth blocks from the focused block, or from the ground block, or both. Also you can hide all backgrounds and show only borders. And there are also many more settings. Please see the GIF instructions and textual instructions on Blockman page:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leodevbro.blockman

Also this instruction is useful:

Tutorial - Blockman - How to show only focused block

https://github.com/leodevbro/vscode-blockman/issues/97

If you still have some difficulties, feel free to reach me on GitHub or here or anywhere and I'll try to help you with your specific preferences.